# Simple PHP error but I'm stumped (PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file)

Tags: php, syntax

I'm new to php and I'm trying to get it set up on my computer so I can develop with it. I am running php 7.4.8 with the path variables set on windows.
I garbed this simple php example from the internet but when I try to compile with code runner on vs code I get this error

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file in C:\Users\admin\Desktop\tempCodeRunnerFile.php on line 2

This is the program:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNvGk.png]

Comment: Error in `tempCode...` and you show us `test.php`?

Comment: I would assume that this is just how the "code runner" extension for vs code runs files. It makes a copy and then executes. could be wrong tho

Comment: Maybe this coderunner just includes file contents as is. What will happen if you remove all `html` tags and have only `<?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>`?

Comment: Yep! It looks like that worked! I get: [Running] php "c:\Users\vicadmin\Desktop\tempCodeRunnerFile.php"
<p>Hello World</p>
[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.148 seconds

Comment: Would you know why that worked @u_mulder?

Comment: I have no idea)